# Restrict number of columns in WordPress core-columns block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to restrict number of columns to three in core-columns block in WordPress Gutenberg.

Desire outcome - WP admin does not allow more then three column from `RangeController` while adding column block in Gutenberg.

[image]

Much appriciate if you any idea.

I tried to use editor.BlockEdit hook to replace existing RangeController but no luck.
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/columns/edit.js

Answer (score 2):

Unregistering [block variations](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/) can restrict the number of available column options when a columns block is inserted.

If you wanted to remove some [default variations](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/columns/variations.js) of the column block that are not 3 columns, you can unregister them by name, eg:

```js
wp.blocks.unregisterBlockVariation('core/columns', 'one-column-full');
wp.blocks.unregisterBlockVariation('core/columns', 'two-columns-equal');
wp.blocks.unregisterBlockVariation('core/columns', 'two-columns-one-third-two-thirds');
wp.blocks.unregisterBlockVariation('core/columns', 'two-columns-two-thirds-one-third');
```

This would show the column inserter as:
[image: Column Block Variation Picker]
NB. *the Editor will still allow the User via the `RangeControl` UI to increase the number of columns to the allowed maximum of 6.*

If you want to completely remove the Users ability to change the number of columns in the UI, I'd then suggest [adding JavaScript](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_editor_assets/) to set the inputs `min|max="3"` and/or hide the control via CSS.